# JAXB nested element Annotation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to know how to annotate the nested elements in XML using JAXB.

My XML should like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="http://127.0.0.1:9089/TCMBCommon-iris/TCMBCommon.svc/GB0010001/">
<title type="text">enqTcibAcctDetailss</title>
<id>http://127.0.0.1:9089/TCMBCommon-iris/TCMBCommon.svc/GB0010001/enqTcibAcctDetailss()</id>
<updated>2016-09-14T10:13:48Z</updated>
<link rel="self" title="enqTcibAcctDetailss" href="enqTcibAcctDetailss()" />
<entry>
    <id>http://127.0.0.1:9089/TCMBCommon-iris/TCMBCommon.svc/GB0010001/enqTcibAcctDetailss('')</id>
    <title type="text" />
    <updated>2016-09-14T10:13:48Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="self" title="enqTcibAcctDetails" href="enqTcibAcctDetailss('78239')" />
    <category term="TCMBCommon-modelsModel.enqTcibAcctDetails" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:CategoryId>1001</d:CategoryId>
            <d:Type>Current Account</d:Type>
            <d:Acc>78239</d:Acc>
            <d:Ccy>GBP</d:Ccy>
            <d:OnlineActualBal>330.47</d:OnlineActualBal>
            <d:RealBalance>330.47</d:RealBalance>
            <d:Sortcode>601613</d:Sortcode>
            <d:Customer>100336</d:Customer>
            <d:ArrangementId>AA16082JD77P</d:ArrangementId>
            <d:Ac1>78239 Rolf Gerling</d:Ac1>
            <d:ProductGroup>CURRENT.ACCOUNTS</d:ProductGroup>
            <d:ProductLine>ACCOUNTS</d:ProductLine>
            <d:ProductName>CURRENT.ACCOUNT</d:ProductName>
            <d:AvailAmt>330.47</d:AvailAmt>
            <d:AvailBalWithLimit>660.94</d:AvailBalWithLimit>
            <d:IbanId>GB22DEMO60161300078239</d:IbanId>
            <d:Branch>Model Bank 201608</d:Branch>
            <d:AcctTransRights>YES</d:AcctTransRights>
            <d:enqTcibAcctDetails_PortfolioNoMvGroup m:type="Bag(TCMBCommon-modelsModel.enqTcibAcctDetails_PortfolioNoMvGroup)">
                <d:element>
                    <d:PortfolioNo></d:PortfolioNo>
                </d:element>
            </d:enqTcibAcctDetails_PortfolioNoMvGroup>
            <d:enqTcibAcctDetails_ShortTitleMvGroup m:type="Bag(TCMBCommon-modelsModel.enqTcibAcctDetails_ShortTitleMvGroup)">
                <d:element>
                    <d:Name>Rolf Gerling</d:Name>
                </d:element>
            </d:enqTcibAcctDetails_ShortTitleMvGroup>
            <d:enqTcibAcctDetails_AccountTitle1MvGroup m:type="Bag(TCMBCommon-modelsModel.enqTcibAcctDetails_AccountTitle1MvGroup)">
                <d:element>
                    <d:AcctName>Current Account</d:AcctName>
                </d:element>
            </d:enqTcibAcctDetails_AccountTitle1MvGroup>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

I want to get the nested element "Property" directly. But I am not able to achieve.

My POJO class for getting the nested elements"Property" alone is

```
@XmlRootElement(name="properties", namespace = 
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)    
class AccountResource {

@XmlElement(name = "Acc", namespace = 
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")
public String accountNumber;

@XmlElement(name = "AcctName")
public String accountName;

@XmlElement(name = "Type")
public String accountType;

@Nullable
@XmlElement(name = "OnlineActualBal")
public Float availableBalance;

@Nullable
@XmlElement(name = "Ccy")
public String currency;

@Nullable
@XmlElement(name = "Customer")
public String customerNumber;

@Nullable
@XmlElement(name = "AcctTransRights")
public Boolean transferRights;
```

Kindly Plz help me how to proceed
1. What is the correct method to annotate the elements using namespace since I am having two or more namespaces.
2. Do we have to use @XMLElementWrapper for this kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. What is the correct method to annotate the elements using namespace since I am having two or more namespaces.

With JAXB you usually have a *Java package* - *XML namespace* mapping, where *XML namespace* is the main/target namespace of your schema. In the Java package you can define a `package-info.java` file with `@XmlSchema` annotation. For example:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package net.opengis.wmts.v_1_0;
```

This has the advantage that you no longer need to specify `namespace` attributes in other annotations in this package. For instance, if you define:

```
@XmlElement(name = "UnitSymbol")
protected String unitSymbol;
```

This actually defines `UnitSymbol` in the namespace `http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0`. Since most elements will be in the target namespace, this will save you a lot of typing.

If, however, you happen to have elements from other namespaces (via `xs:element/@ref`, for instance), you still can use the `namespace` attribute of the annotation to specify the namespace. For example:

```
@XmlElement(name = "UOM", namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1")
protected DomainMetadataType uom;
```

> 2. Do we have to use @XMLElementWrapper for this kind

In this case, no. You'll just have something like:

```
@XmlElement(name="properties")
private AccountResource properties;
```

And that's it.

You'd need `@XmlElementWrapper` if you wanted a structure like:

```
<m:properties>
    <m:property>
        <d:CategoryId>1001</d:CategoryId>
        <d:Type>Current Account</d:Type>
        <d:Acc>78239</d:Acc>
        <d:Ccy>GBP</d:Ccy>
        <!-- ... -->
    </m:property>
    <m:property>
        <!-- ... -->
    </m:property>
    <!-- ... -->
</m:properties>
```

---

Generally, my recommendation would be to define a XML Schema which describes your XML structure. You could then generate your classes from this schema.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, It helped me more. Thanks :) But  If we are taking the soap response how the annotations would be. Since I have WSDL I am able to create required POJO. But I want to know how to use that for the service call. Also, I am trying to create Retrofit instance. I didnt get any idea how to proceed.